# Zend Framework and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: php, visual-studio, zend-framework, visual-studio-2012

I wonder if there's any possibility of getting `Zend Framework` to work with `Visual Studio 2012`? I'm interested in both, free and paid solutions. I'd like the support for `ZF` in `VS2012` (project creation - catalog structure etc.). Earlier I used to work with `Netbeans`, but I would rather `VS`.

Does anyone tried any integration plugins for that case? I found [VS.Php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php), but it's not integrated with `Zend`.

Comment: The intellisense should work reasonably well in VS. You will likely need to use the CLI for Zend_Tool for project creation and any other needs you may have for Zend_Tool. Good Luck.

Comment: Did you get this working? If so, could you provide an answer of how you did it and how it went?

Comment: Unfortunately not:( I'm just using Netbeans for developping Zend apps. If you find something, please let me know!